# jQuery Cycle plugin- How to return the index number of the currently displayed slide?

Tags: jquery, indexing, return, cycle, slide

I'm currently using [Malsup's Cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/)  . I am just wondering is it possible to have cycle plugin return the index number of the currently displayed slide??

I want to change the content of the page when a specific slide is active. Don't know how to achieve that..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this:

```
//on before function
before: function (curr, next, opts) {
    alert(opts.nextSlide + " of " + opts.slideCount);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks so much Sudhir! I'm a beginner in coding, how do I return the current slide number as a variable oppose to popping an alert like the one you showed me? Thanks!

Comment: var current = opts.nextSlide;

Answer (score 4):

To get the current slide use:

```
before: function (curr, next, opts) {
    alert("Current slide " + opts.currSlide);
}
```